# Filter only uppercase words from file

Tags: regex, powershell, foreach

I have an output.txt file which has around 1000 words that looks like this:

```
SESSIONDAYOFWEEK
FILMTITLELONGALT
tblTrans_Ticket.
ADMITDETAILSALT2
MESSAGESTUB2ALT3
StartDayOfWeek
Description
MESSAGESTUB2ALT2
FILMTITLESHORTALT
Applications
TICKETTYPELONGALT
```

I need to filter that file, select only words that only have UPPER CASE characters, and get rid of those that have lower case characters.

I run this command in PowerShell:

```
Get-Content .\out.txt | ForEach-Object if ($_.IsUpper) {Write-Host $_}
```

and the shell parse all the words one by one and for each words prints me:

```
ForEach-Object : Input name "if" cannot be resolved to a method.
At line:1 char:25
+ ... et-Content .\out.txt | ForEach-Object if ($_.IsUpper) {Write-Host $_}
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (TAIL:PSObject) [ForEach-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

I don't understand where am I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably with regex.

```
Get-Content .\out.txt | Where-Object { $_ -cmatch "\b[A-Z0-9_]+\b" }
```

`Where-Object` acts as a filter, allowing anything that matches through and discarding anything that doesn't match.

`-cmatch` will do case-sensitive regex match

**Regex explanation:**

`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

`A-Z` a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90)

`0-9` a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57)

`_` matches the character `_` literally

`\b` assert position at a word boundary

You can remove `0-9` and `_` if you don't want to allow words with those characters through the filter.

See: https://regex101.com/r/CfgEmU/1

Comment: Good answer, though it may be simpler to just exclude anything with a lower case letter like `|?{$_ -cnotmatch '[a-z]'}`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-cmatch` operator for case-sensitive matching against a regex ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions)):

```
Get-Content .\out.txt | Where-Object { $_ -cmatch  '^\p{Lu}+$' }
```

- `-cmatch` is the case-sensitive variant of the [`-match` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#-match) (whose alias is `-imatch`); given that `-match` is case-insensitive, `-cmatch` must be used in order to detect case distinctions.
- `\p{Lu}` matches a single uppercase character - including accented non-ASCII characters such as `Ü`<sup>[1]</sup> - and adding `+` matches one or more in a row. Enclosing the expression in `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) means that only lines entirely made up of uppercase characters are matched.

  - [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) suggests `-cnotmatch '\p{Ll}'` instead, which works slightly differently: it would eliminate lines that contain *at least one lowercase* character, which means that lines are kept even if they (also) contain non-letter characters (as long as there's no lowercase letter).

An alternative with `Select-String` that may perform better:

```
Select-String -CaseSensitive '^\p{Lu}+$' .\out.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
```

`Select-String` too is case-insensitive by default (as is PowerShell in general), so the 
`-CaseSensitive` switch is required here.

Note that, despite its name, `Select-String` as of PowerShell Core 6.1.0 doesn't support outputting the matched lines directly; instead, it outputs match-information objects whose `.Line` property contains the matched line, hence the need for `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line`.
[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7713) proposes adding a new switch parameter to support direct output of the matched strings.

---

As for **what you tried**:

The code to be executed by the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet must be passed as a *script block* - i.e., a piece of code enclosed in `{ ... }`.

You neglected to do that, which caused the syntax error you saw.

Also, the `[string]` type (a .NET string) does not have an `.IsUpper()` method (and even if it did, you forgot the `()` after `.IsUpper`).

Only the `[char]` type has an `.IsUpper()` method, namely a *static* one, which you can call as follows: `[char]::IsUpper('A')` - but you'd have to call this method in a loop for each character in your input string:

```
Get-Content .\out.txt | Where-Object { 
  foreach ($c in $_.ToCharArray()) { if (-not [char]::IsUpper($c)) { return $False } }
  $True
}
```

Finally, don't use `Write-Host` to return *results* - `Write-Host` prints to the *console only* - you won't be able to capture or redirect such output<sup>[2]</sup>. Instead, use `Write-Output` or, better yet, rely on PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior: simply using `$_` as a statement of its own will output it - any expression or command you neither capture nor redirect is automatically output (sent to the success output stream).

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, using character range expression `[A-Z]` would only recognize ASCII-range (English) uppercase characters.</sup>

<sup>[2] Never in PSv4-, but with additional effort you can in PSv5+ - but the point is that `Write-Host` is not meant for outputting *results* (data).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

howdy Francesco Mantovani,

as others have mentioned, the `[string]` type does NOT have an `.IsUpper` property. the `[char]` type has an `.IsUpper()` *method*, but it also lacks a *property* with that name. [*grin*]

you can test for all-upper-case array items thus ...

```
$Collection.Where({$_ -ceq $_.ToUpper()})
```

hope that helps,
lee